# Proper way of signing message in web3 and recovering in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js

Can anyone help me with the proper implemented documentation on how to sign a message in `web3` and then the secure way of recovering it in `solidity smartcontract`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the example of how to do it in Solidity docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/solidity-by-example.html#micropayment-channel

Comment: Signature mismatched always even if I followed the documentation. The difference I did in my implementation is I haven't used metamask. I simply generated signature using   const signedMessagea = await web3.eth.sign(sha3, signer.address) method and recovered in solidity.

Comment: @NinjaMAN did you ever sort this out? I did use metamask to sign using `signTypedData_V4`, but still the signatures don't match when I recover in solidity. I can recover it off-chain though... very odd.